# java/scala incompatible types, when casing (or using instanceof) a scala class to java class, even though the scala class extends the java class

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

this is pretty much the code setup:

```
// java
public class JavaA { 

}

// scala
class ScalaA() extends JavaA {

}
```

but then in java, if i have an instance of ScalaA somewhere (or even if its null), but try to do this:

```
ScalaA scalaA = ...
if (scalaA instanceof JavaA) { ... }
```

on the line with instanceof, intellij doesn't show any error. but if i try to compile the code, i get the `java: incompatible types`

i've included the scala sdk as a project depedency, the java versions are correct, ive tried invalidating the cache/restarting, etc, but it doesnt seem to work. does anyone know how to fix this?

also, the scala class, it's compiled in a .jar file, and i imported it as a dependency. just like with the scala SDK and stuff

edit: i found a "solution" that seems to work; its not really a fix, but it works for now. i basically just used a function called "forceCast", and the code looks like this:

```
public static <T> T forceCast(Object value) {
    try {
        return (T) value;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then

```
ScalaA scalaA = ...
JavaA javaA = forceCast(scalaA);
```

realistically, an exception should never be thrown in this case. this actually did fix my issue, and let me compile the code. im not sure about using instanceof, but i guess what i could do is just cast `scalaA` to an object, and do it that way

Comment: Could you give instructions how to go from an empty directory to actually seeing that specific error? That may dramatically increase the chances of someone discovering what's going wrong.

Comment: create a java project, and then the scala class i found the problem in, was from a minecraft mod "forge multipart". so i included that jar as a dependency allowing me to use the classes. the exact details: the scala class inherits "TileEntity" and is called "TIleMultipart". if i have a variable of the TIleMultipart and try to cast it to a TileEntity or the other way round, it shows no error. but when i try to compile it, it shows the incompatible types error